# Query for custom post type?

Tags: get-posts, custom-post-types

I have installed the [Custom Post Type UI plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/). After activation of this plugin I have created a custom post type called `portfolio`. Now I want to use this on the portfolio page in the front-end. How do I fetch *all post that are of custom post type `portfolio`*?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => array('post', 'portfolio') ) );
```

which shows both normal posts and posts inside `portfolio` type

or

```
query_posts('post_type=portfolio');
```

for only `portfolio`.

Use as normal WP Query - read the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Usage and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

```
<?php 
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'showposts' => 10 
    ) );  
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: This is a fairly old answer - but to be clear, there is not the way you should being doing this.  It will almost inevitably lead to 404s and a host of other problems. Please see @kaiser's answers or [this post on why you shouldn't use `query_posts()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts/50762#50762)

Answer (score 18):

*Late answer as the main answer uses `query_posts()`, which should **never** be done.*

### Use a filter

Use the `pre_get_posts` filter and just set the `portfolio` post type for the main query. Use [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to determine where you want to have this filter.

### Quick Example

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/* Plugin Name: (#6417) "Portfolio" post type in query */

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_6417_portfolio_posts' );
function wpse_6417_portfolio_posts( $query )
{
    if (
        ! $query->is_main_query()
        // Here we can check for all Conditional Tags
        OR ! $query->is_archive() // For e.g.: Every archive will feature both post types
    )
        return $query;

    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'portfolio' ) );

    return $query;
}
```

#### Disclaimer

The above code is a plugin, but can simply get stuffed in the `functions.php` file of your theme (which is **not** recommended).

Comment: why is it not recommended to add it to functions? Surely, if the site admin changes the theme they would need to address how to display the portfolio on the home page with this new theme anyway. So, I would say it is just as valid to add this in functions rather than a plugin. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PhillHealey As you said, the data would be invisible and you would have to copy and paste the code around. Heavy, logic modifications to queries are best served via plugins, while displaying and styling should be kept in themes.

Comment: Not if that code is specific to the theme.

Comment: @PhillHealey A post type should **never** be specific to a theme.

Comment: Ok, if you want to get in some tit-for-tat over absolutes then fine. However, It's just not correct to say that none design specific code should be pushed out to a plugin. There are lots of times when that's not appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Add this code to your **child themes functions file** (recommended) to add your single CPT pages to your main loop

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_types_to_loop' );

function add_custom_post_types_to_loop( $query ) {

if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )

$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'portfolio' ) );

return $query;

}
```

Source http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Or [create a custom archive-portfolio.php page template](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-post-types-archive-page-in-wordpress/) which will only display your CPT pages. This only needs to be done if you haven't added a archive page using the plugin settings.

Example: 'has_archive'  => true,

You can also control how many pages are displayed and the order in which they're displayed on the archive page using this code:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cpt_items' );

function cpt_items( $query ) {

if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'portfolio' ) ) {

$query->set( 'posts_per_page', '8' );

$query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );

    }

}
```